# printing multiple NR from one file based on the value from other file using awk

Tags: awk

I want to print out multiple rows from one file based on the input values from the other.
Following is the representation of file 1:

```
2
4
1
```

Following is the representation of file 2:

```
MANCHKLGO
kflgklfdg
fhgjpiqog
fkfjdkfdg
fghjshdjs
jgfkgjfdk
ghftrysba
gfkgfdkgj
jfkjfdkgj
```

Based on the first column of the first file, the code should first print the second row of the second file followed by fourth row and then the first row of the second file. Hence, the output should be following:

```
kflgklfdg
fkfjdkfdg
MANCHKLGO
```

Following are the codes that I tried:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}FNR in a{print $0}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

However, as expected, the output is not in the order as it first printed the first row then the second and fourth row is the last. How can I print the NR from the second file as exactly in the order given in the first file?

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the question with the code that I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[$1]}' file2 file1
kflgklfdg
fkfjdkfdg
MANCHKLGO
```

#### How it works

- `NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}`

  This saves the contents of file2 in array `a`.
- `print a[$1]`

  For each number in file1, we print the desired line of file2.

#### Solution to earlier version of question

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[2*$1];print a[2*$1+1]}' file2 file1
fkfjdkfdg
fghjshdjs
gfkgfdkgj
jfkjfdkgj
kflgklfdg
fhgjpiqog
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I modified my question as I did not try any code for the question that I asked earlier so I decided to modify question with the code that I tried (I actually changed the first file itself so that I can print one row at a time).

Comment: @MaulikUpadhyay OK.  Answer updated to print one line at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Another take:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {a[$1]; order[n++] = $1; next} 
    FNR in a {lines[FNR] = $0} 
    END {for (i=0; i<n; i++) print lines[order[i]]}
' file1.txt file2.txt
```

This version stores fewer lines in memory, if your files are huge.